# New Format list of figure

Tags: table-of-contents

This is what I want :
[image]

I'm really being crazy with latex.

this is my code for toc :

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
  \@restonecolfalse
\fi

\chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
       \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
{\raggedleft\normalfont Hal \par}%
      \@starttoc{toc}%
 \linespread{1}
 \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
```

Hal is page number.

could anyone help me please ?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: it would be good if you would show a code example for starting, showing your effort and the class, packages and settings you are using, instead of "Please do all for me, and start from zero".

Comment: I create for toc, I'll show you ya, wait.

Comment: I'm use report class, package = tocloft,  I use lyx instead of texmaker.I have to crate the same format for lyx and texmaker in my highschool task. thanks for the advice sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addto\captionsindonesian{\renewcommand\listfigurename{Daftar Tabel}}

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase} 
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{%
  \hfill\null\\[2\baselineskip]\bfseries No.\hfill\phantom{Hal}Judul\phantom{No.}\hfill Hal}
\renewcommand\cftafterloftitleskip{1\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftfigindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[!hb]A\caption{test one}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!hb]A\caption{test two}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\vskip-2\baselineskip`?

Comment: @lockstep: to reduce the default vertical skip between the line with the headings and the first entry, as in the OP's image.

Comment: @Gonzalo: You can manage the skip after the heading by setting the length `\cftafterloftitleskip` to `2\baselineskip`

Comment: @Werner: yes, it's better to do so. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Also, you need modify `\phantom{PAG.}` to `\phantom{Hal}` to get the appropriate centered spacing. You'll see that, at the moment, it is centered slightly to the right.

Comment: @Weerner: right again. I was reusing this code and forgot to make some changes

Comment: sir how can the figure counter 1,2,3,..(Continuous numbering of figures) without this code ?

'\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}'

Comment: Sir, thanks so much, you solve two my problem lof&lot also for counter. for list of table, I just replace lof to lot. Excellent :-)

Comment: @Verly: you're welcome. I don't understand your problem with the counters, though. There's another question of yours where this issue was (apparently) solved. Do you still have any problem with the counters?

Comment: not for table and figure coz it have solved by your answer, but yes for equation. my equation have format I.1 for chapter 1 and II.1 for chapter II. could I use chngcntr.sty ? \counterwithout{equation}{chapter} ?

Comment: @Verly: yes, you could.